# Aligning DIV without margin or float

Tags: html, css

I a template, I have five DIV elements underneath each other on a HTML page. (Logo, top menu, sub menu, content, footer).

I want the user to be able to set the alignment for each DIV in a CMS: left, center, right.
Those settings I used to translate to

```
margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0px; // right
margin-right: auto; margin-left: 0px; //left 
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; // center
```

for each DIV. Now however, I want the user to be able to specify a real **margin for each side** as well. That, of course, makes the `margin` attribute **unusable for positioning**.

I do **not** want to use **float** for the positioning as this will bring additional layout troubles. I would have to surround the DIVs with `overflow: auto` wrappers and so on.

My current idea is to have **two nested DIVs**. The outer one takes care of the positioning (margin:auto), while the inner one sets the user-specified margins.

I fear however that this will bring me additional woes when variable widths come into play, or inner padding.

**Is there a simpler way than that to align a block element left, right, or center?**

IE7 used to listen to `<div align=center>` and center block elements surrounded by it. Something like that (but valid and cross-browser) would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I position `DIV`s in <`table`> elements and then I hide from the angry crowd of CSS purists with torches and pitchforks. :)

Comment: :) :) Even better: One could put nice <div>s into the source code, but change them to <table>s using JQuery later. Then obfuscate the JQuery, get a torch and pitchfork of your own and join the crowd. ;)

Comment: I ended up doing it some other way - I don't remember right now - but I'm accepting this for the laughs :)

Comment: A bit late to chime in on this, but tables should never be used for layout. You could probably work with css using display: inline-table to get what you're after.

Comment: in a world of tableless, table is not a option for me.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into a CSS Grids component to handle the flexibility and cross browser compatibility you're looking for.  I implemented a similar feature into a CMS once using [YUI Grids CSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/).  There are several other CSS Grids solutions out there, like [the 960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) and [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), but I don't have any personal experience with those.

It's not exactly simpler, but it is easier when dealing with cross browser compatibility.

Comment: I am really not keen to add a grid system to what is already quite a big thing, but you may be right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a margin on the *page*, encapsulate all your other divs in the user-modifiable one.

Comment: Nope, the margin is a setting that can be made for each DIV individually.

Comment: right, but if you encase them all inside something else, it should be based off the enclosing div, no? Or, at least that's what I do on sites I've managed before

Comment: my understanding is that margins are based-off the enclosing element, and should therefore be based off an enclosing div if everything else is tucked inside it

Answer (score 0):

If you won't care about any border, paddding may be an option?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... padding is a cross-browser nightmare and I fear that even more than I fear float. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#topmenu, #submenu, #content, #footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

should allow to float any of your five div to left or right. edit: and other divs should remain in place.

Answer (score 0):

> "Now however, I want the user to be
>   able to specify a real margin for each
>   side as well. That, of course, makes
>   the margin attribute unusable for
>   positioning."

You could use a dynamic style sheet w/ php. You can pass the user specified variables to the style sheet... something like this:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/css");

$left = $_POST['left'];
$right = $_POST['right'];

?>

div#right {
     margin-left: auto; 
     margin-right: <? echo $right ?>px; // right
}

div#left {
     margin-right: auto; 
     margin-left: <? echo $left ?>px; //left 
}
```